# Using proxy for web socket using apache 2.4

Tags: apache, proxy, websocket

I'm currently running a websocket server. I want to be able to access this through ws.mydomain.com

The web socket is listening on port 8080.
I'm running Apache 2.4 and my configuration looks look this.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ws.mydomain.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Location />
            ProxyPass ws://xxx.xxx.x.xx:8080/
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

when I try to connect on websocket.org it won't let me while I'm pretty sure they are doing something similar theirself in their example.

Does anyone know what might be going wrong here?